# Conversion of to_date says missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select A,B,C,
TO_DATE(year  ||'-'||  LPAD(month,2,0)  ||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD') as firstday,
LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(year  ||'-'||  LPAD(month,2,0)  ||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) as lastday
from test;
```

> Error : "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: You don't need `LPAD`. If you don't provide a day, then Oracle takes the first day of given months, so `TO_DATE(year  ||'-'|| month,'YYYY-MM')` works in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole lot of things.

```
SQL> with test (year, month) as
  2    (select '2022', '4' from dual)
  3  select to_date(year ||'-'|| lpad(month, 2, '0') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
01-APR-22

SQL>
```

---

Though, as it seems you want the 1st of that month, you can shorten it to

```
SQL> with test (year, month) as
  2    (select '2022', '4' from dual)
  3  select to_date(year || month, 'yyyymm') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
01-APR-22

SQL>
```

---

The `LAST_DAY` option:

```
SQL> with test (year, month) as
  2    (select '2022', '4' from dual)
  3  select
  4             to_date(year  ||'-'||  lpad(month,2,0)  ||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD')  as firstday,
  5    last_day(to_date(year  ||'-'||  lpad(month,2,0)  ||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) as lastday
  6  from test;

FIRSTDAY   LASTDAY
---------- ----------
01.04.2022 30.04.2022

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, When I try to pass that output to LAST_DAY() function it says ""FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: If you're referring to edited question's code, then there's a comma missing after one of the labels - I'll let you discover it.

Comment: Comma was missing at end of line2. BUt after correcting it facing same issue.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, because - it works for me. See edited answer.